# Problems using TensorFlow with ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wrote this code, but receive this error:
"TypeError: x must be dict; got ndarray"

```
dados_x = preprocessing.normalize(dados_x,axis=0,norm='l2')
dados_treino, dados_teste, valor_treino, valor_teste = train_test_split(dados_x, dados_y, test_size=0.1)
```

and

```
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x=dados_treino, y=valor_treino,
batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
# Train the Model
model.train(input_fn, steps=num_steps)
```

This error occurs on model.training

I'm find on internet, but not understanding this solution.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like `dados_treino` is not a dictionary?

Comment: No, dados_treino is ndarray.

Comment: Shouldn't it be dictionary? I mean, you need to pass feed_dict to `train`.

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question. Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?